# Archive Submissions Failure - The app references non-public symbols (WatchKit)

Tags: ios, watchkit

I would like to submit my iOS to beta but can not upload the archive because of this failing message with Watchkit. I'm still developing the Watchkit part want to get the main app out to testers. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I checked the docs and didnt get a link to guidelines for submitting watch app. Is it too early ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you shouldn’t try to submit anything built with a beta SDK (such as the one that includes WatchKit support) to the App Store. You’ll need to remove the WK bits from your app—or move them to a branch—and then build the app with the current public version of Xcode to submit it to the App Store.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured. I guess I was just hoping for a simple flag or something.

Comment: You can also create a copy of your main app target that doesn't include the WatchKit bits, which can still be compiled with Xcode 6.1.